# How Schedule a Azure Data Factory Trigger for 30 minute intervals per day

Tags: azure-data-factory

I how like a create a Azure Data Factory Triggger to run every day at 30min intervals. However, I don't seem to be able to create 30mins interval per day. The nearest I appear to get is 1 hour.

E.g, I would like 6:30, 7:00, 7:30, 8:00 etc.
But as you can see I appear to only schedule hourly per day

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this , its more simpler , its you want to start at :00 or:30 min mark .
Then set the start time as accordingly
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

I simply adjusted the execution times to include start minutes of 0, with interval of 30

[image]